# Redirect jetty request to apache

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd, jetty

I am centos 7. I have two servers running apache and jetty. Jetty at port 8080 and apache at 80. Now I have to redirect all request from jetty to apache home page like. if a user type http://my-ip:8080/some-thing in browser, it should be redirected to http://my-ip/index.php.

Comment: What have you tried already? Can you post the relevant sections of your apache config?

Comment: I have just tried to use REDIRECT directive in apache but it does not work.

Comment: You'll need to post the section of your apache config here so people can tell you what's wrong with it.